# Security: Plaid vs Quicken vs Mint

Tags: authentication, privacy, account-security, banks

Why are people so quick to criticize **Plaid** for using login info when trusted apps like **Mint** do the same thing? They **require username and password for bank info**, but seem to be trusted. I wanted to use Plaid to build my own fintech app but was concerned about the raised privacy concerns so want to better understand why people trust other budget managing apps over an api like Plaids.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such criticism?

Comment: Plaid is a service provider, Mint is a service.  While they're both guilty of doing something security peeps aren't comfortable with, Plaid is a higher-impact example.  As @schroeder says, however, we'd need to know what criticisms you're looking at to have useful feedback.